# How to install and run docker in windows 10 home edition

Tags: virtualbox, docker

I know there are couple of tutorials out there regarding this. However, nothing seems to work in my case. Let me explain, the steps that I tried so far and where I finally got stuck.

1. As hyper V is not supported in my windows 10 home edition I downloaded and installed Docker tools for windows from :

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v1.12.3

2. I already had VirtualBox (5.1.6) installed in my computer. So, I started Kitematic after docker tools were installed. It showed the following error:

`Error: connect ENOENT //./pipe/docker_engine`

I chose `USE VIRTUALBOX` from my available options and then it complains about my `VT-X/AMD-V` not being enabled. I enabled `Virtualization` from my BIOS and repeated the same process.

3. This time my Docker VM was created successfully (I can see the new VM from my VirtualBox Manager. However, it showed a big error message right after the VM creation was done:

```
 Command failed: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default,Docker Machine Version: 0.8.2, build e18a919,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:49813,() Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,() Calling .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling .DriverName,(flag-lookup) Calling .GetCreateFlags,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:49818,() Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,() Calling .GetMachineName,(default) Calling .GetMachineName,(default) Calling .DriverName,(default) Calling .GetCreateFlags,(default) Calling .SetConfigFromFlags,(default) Calling .PreCreateCheck,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe --version,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | 5.1.6r110634,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | Hyper-V is not installed.,(default) DBG | %!(EXTRA *exec.Error=exec: "vmms.exe": executable file not found in %PATH%)COMMAND: wmic cpu get VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled ,(default) DBG | TRUE ,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | local Boot2Docker ISO version: v1.12.2,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) Calling .GetConfigRaw,(default) Calling .Create,(default) DBG | local Boot2Docker ISO version: v1.12.3,(default) DBG | Creating disk image...,(default) DBG | Creating 20000 MB hard disk image...,(default) DBG | Writing magic tar header,(default) DBG | Writing SSH key tar header,(default) DBG | Calling inner createDiskImage,(default) DBG | &{C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe [C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe convertfromraw stdin C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk 20971520000 --format VMDK] []    []      false [] [] [] []  },(default) DBG | Starting command,(default) DBG | Copying to stdin,(default) DBG | Filling zeroes,(default) DBG | Closing STDIN,(default) DBG | Waiting on cmd,(default) DBG | Converting from raw image file="stdin" to file="C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk"...,(default) DBG | Creating dynamic image with size 20971520000 bytes (20000MB)...,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe createvm --basefolder C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default --name default --register,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Virtual machine 'default' is created and registered.,(default) DBG | UUID: 82ffd2ab-46fb-42c1-893c-7a072642f60e,(default) DBG | Settings file: 'C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\default.vbox',(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | VM CPUS: 1,(default) DBG | VM Memory: 2048,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --firmware bios --bioslogofadein off --bioslogofadeout off --bioslogodisplaytime 0 --biosbootmenu disabled --ostype Linux26_64 --cpus 1 --memory 2048 --acpi on --ioapic on --rtcuseutc on --natdnshostresolver1 off --natdnsproxy1 on --cpuhotplug off --pae on --hpet on --hwvirtex on --nestedpaging on --largepages on --vtxvpid on --accelerate3d off --boot1 dvd,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --nic1 nat --nictype1 82540EM --cableconnected1 on,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe storagectl default --name SATA --add sata --hostiocache on,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe storageattach default --storagectl SATA --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe storageattach default --storagectl SATA --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe guestproperty set default /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix /,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe guestproperty set default /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | setting up shareDir,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add default --name c/Users --hostpath \\?\c:\Users --automount,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe setextradata default VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/c/Users 1,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo default --machinereadable,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | name="default",(default) DBG | groups="/",(default) DBG | ostype="Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64-bit)",(default) DBG | UUID="82ffd2ab-46fb-42c1-893c-7a072642f60e",(default) DBG | CfgFile="C:\\Users\\bondrul\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\default.vbox",(default) DBG | SnapFldr="C:\\Users\\bondrul\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Snapshots",(default) DBG | LogFldr="C:\\Users\\bondrul\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Logs",(default) DBG | hardwareuuid="82ffd2ab-46fb-42c1-893c-7a072642f60e",(default) DBG | memory=2048,(default) DBG | pagefusion="off",(default) DBG | vram=8,(default) DBG | cpuexecutioncap=100,(default) DBG | hpet="on",(default) DBG | chipset="piix3",(default) DBG | firmware="BIOS",(default) DBG | cpus=1,(default) DBG | pae="on",(default) DBG | longmode="on",(default) DBG | triplefaultreset="off",(default) DBG | apic="on",(default) DBG | x2apic="off",(default) DBG | cpuid-portability-level=0,(default) DBG | bootmenu="disabled",(default) DBG | boot1="dvd",(default) DBG | boot2="dvd",(default) DBG | boot3="disk",(default) DBG | boot4="none",(default) DBG | acpi="on",(default) DBG | ioapic="on",(default) DBG | biosapic="apic",(default) DBG | biossystemtimeoffset=0,(default) DBG | rtcuseutc="on",(default) DBG | hwvirtex="on",(default) DBG | nestedpaging="on",(default) DBG | largepages="on",(default) DBG | vtxvpid="on",(default) DBG | vtxux="on",(default) DBG | paravirtprovider="default",(default) DBG | effparavirtprovider="kvm",(default) DBG | VMState="poweroff",(default) DBG | VMStateChangeTime="2016-11-15T20:25:35.134000000",(default) DBG | monitorcount=1,(default) DBG | accelerate3d="off",(default) DBG | accelerate2dvideo="off",(default) DBG | teleporterenabled="off",(default) DBG | teleporterport=0,(default) DBG | teleporteraddress="",(default) DBG | teleporterpassword="",(default) DBG | tracing-enabled="off",(default) DBG | tracing-allow-vm-access="off",(default) DBG | tracing-config="",(default) DBG | autostart-enabled="off",(default) DBG | autostart-delay=0,(default) DBG | defaultfrontend="",(default) DBG | storagecontrollername0="SATA",(default) DBG | storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerinstance0="0",(default) DBG | storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerportcount0="30",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerbootable0="on",(default) DBG | "SATA-0-0"="C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso",(default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-0-0"="583a8394-8dbc-4319-a19f-420d967c83ad",(default) DBG | "SATA-tempeject"="off",(default) DBG | "SATA-IsEjected"="off",(default) DBG | "SATA-1-0"="C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk",(default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-1-0"="1e38af75-2aa9-4b64-83d6-2bca0db86bc2",(default) DBG | "SATA-2-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-3-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-4-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-5-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-6-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-7-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-8-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-9-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-10-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-11-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-12-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-13-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-14-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-15-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-16-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-17-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-18-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-19-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-20-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-21-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-22-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-23-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-24-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-25-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-26-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-27-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-28-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-29-0"="none",(default) DBG | natnet1="nat",(default) DBG | macaddress1="080027B58655",(default) DBG | cableconnected1="on",(default) DBG | nic1="nat",(default) DBG | nictype1="82540EM",(default) DBG | nicspeed1="0",(default) DBG | mtu="0",(default) DBG | sockSnd="64",(default) DBG | sockRcv="64",(default) DBG | tcpWndSnd="64",(default) DBG | tcpWndRcv="64",(default) DBG | nic2="none",(default) DBG | nic3="none",(default) DBG | nic4="none",(default) DBG | nic5="none",(default) DBG | nic6="none",(default) DBG | nic7="none",(default) DBG | nic8="none",(default) DBG | hidpointing="ps2mouse",(default) DBG | hidkeyboard="ps2kbd",(default) DBG | uart1="off",(default) DBG | uart2="off",(default) DBG | uart3="off",(default) DBG | uart4="off",(default) DBG | lpt1="off",(default) DBG | lpt2="off",(default) DBG | audio="dsound",(default) DBG | clipboard="disabled",(default) DBG | draganddrop="disabled",(default) DBG | vrde="off",(default) DBG | usb="off",(default) DBG | ehci="off",(default) DBG | xhci="off",(default) DBG | SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="c/Users",(default) DBG | SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\c:\Users",(default) DBG | vcpenabled="off",(default) DBG | vcpscreens=0,(default) DBG | vcpfile="C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\default.webm",(default) DBG | vcpwidth=1024,(default) DBG | vcpheight=768,(default) DBG | vcprate=512,(default) DBG | vcpfps=25,(default) DBG | GuestMemoryBalloon=0,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | Searching for hostonly interface for IPv4: 192.168.99.1 and Mask: ffffff00,(default) DBG | Not found,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif create,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | 0%...,(default) DBG | Progress state: E_INVALIDARG,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Assertion failed: [!aInterfaceName.isEmpty()] at 'F:\tinderbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (74) in long __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Bstr,class com::Bstr,class com::Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0038).,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Please contact the product vendor!,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | GUID: 1c7d7fa9-bfba-42d9-8664-6b0ad031df0a,(default) DBG | DHCP: Enabled,(default) DBG | IPAddress: 169.254.217.218,(default) DBG | NetworkMask: 255.255.0.0,(default) DBG | IPV6Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:e996:d207:6c60:d9da,(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64,(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:03,(default) DBG | MediumType: Ethernet,(default) DBG | Status: Up,(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter,(default) DBG | ,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue,open C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBox.log: The system cannot find the path specified.,notifying bugsnag: [Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue],`
```

4. The error message says, `reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue`. I am already using 5.1.6 where 5.1.8 is that latest version.
5. I checked the network settings of the VM created by kitematic. I found the interface is attached to `NAT`by default. I changed that to `Host only` and tried restarted the VM; that got me the following error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu Test.

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I then fixed the issue following the instruction from

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68590&start=450#p345379

6. I then shut the VM off and tried to connect from kitematic and ended up with the same error as before. I tried turing the VM on and trying to connect kitematic while the VM is running, this time kitematic went to a state where it keeps on loading for ever.

I am out of ideas. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: You should upgrade to 5.1.18

Comment: Can you please format the error message?  I spent 10 minutes trying to format it, and I still wasn't done with it, its unreadable in its current from.  You should also provide us the relevant information from, `C:\Users\bondrul\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBox.log`, in your question.  We don't need every line only the relevant information surrounding the failure to create a network adapter.  Can you provide the properties on the `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` Adaptor?

Comment: Any security software you have installed will cause a conflict.